# Использования кэш памяти в объектно ориентированном и процедурном программировании

Tags: c++, ооп, кэширование

Какая разница между OOP & Procedural подходами в рамках кэш память(процес использования памяти, загрузка...)?

Comment: читайте и  разберетесь  - https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/125-the-virtual-table/   https://pabloariasal.github.io/2017/06/10/understanding-virtual-tables/

Answer (score 2):

В очень большом числе случаев, вызов метода затрагивает не все члены-данные объекта, а только их небольшую часть. (Это не всегда так, но в подавляющем большинстве практически встречающихся задач.) Шина память-процессор устроена так, что при обращении к отдельному байту, в кеш попадет некоторая область памяти, содержащая этот байт. Т.е. по шине будут переданы в т.ч. данные которые нам не понадобятся.

Рассмотрим сценарий:

```
struct ABC { 
    int a,b,c,d;
    void inc() { ++a; }
};
ABC abc_vetcor[1024];
....
for( ABC& a : abc_vetcor )
    a.inc();
```

В через шину память будет перекачено `sizeof(int)*4*1024` байт, хотя для выполнения поставленной задачи достаточной было четверти этих данных.

Чтобы оптимизировать передачу данных через шину нужно изменить упорядочение данных в памяти, так чтобы члены данных `a` принадлежащие разным объектам лежали рядом. Например:

```
struct ABC { 
    int a,b,c,d;
    void inc() { ++a; }
};
template<size_t size>
struct ABC_vector { 
    int a[size];
    int b[size];
    int c[size];
    int d[size];
    void inc_all() {
       for(int& a_i : a ) ++a_i; 
    }
};
```

Однако, здесь мы вынуждены были скопировать и "раскрыть" метод `inc()`. Но это противоречит инкапсуляции, которая является краеугольным камнем ООП(!).

В принципе, для C++ существуют технические приемы и библиотеки, которые позволяют реорганизовывать массивы объектов в памяти, оставаясь в рамках ООП. (CRTP подход + использование метаданных.) Но это сильно усложняет код, и не решает проблему других часто встречающихся сценариев. Например обход коллекций разнородных объектов.